# WebView in RhoMobile

Tags: rhomobile

I am new to rhoMobile, i am trying to open google page from application.rb
Read the webview document, but didn't find the way to put the app in snc.

```
application.rb
```

{
  def on_ui_created
    WebView.navigate("http://www.mysite.com")
  end
}

Please help me out how to proceed. 
Suggest some gud tutorial to start up. (all tutorial shows only Model creation)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic tutorial. If you go through the documentation step by step you should see it.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/rhoelements-tutorial

Also you have the Sample chapter right in the main page

http://docs.rhomobile.com/

Sample Apps

**API samples:** A simple Rhodes application which demonstrates all features.

**TrackR:** Source code for third party iPhone/Android app for Pivotal Tracker.

**Rhostore:** Simple store application which we show you how to build in the Rhodes Tutorial.

**Rhostore Bulk:** Simple store application demonstrating how to use the bulk sync feature.

**Webinar Samples:** A collection of all samples shown in the webinars.